# The difference between AWS Amplify and amazon-cognito-identity-js?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm reviewing this demo of how to integrate Cognito with Angular, and it [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) for the authorization service.

It seems that is what we should be using, but other tutorials install [AWS Amplify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-amplify) as a whole:

```
npm i aws-amplify
```

Curious what the difference is and whether one is more current than the other?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`amazon-cognito-identity-js` used to be a separate package specifically for `Cognito`. Recently they've been bundling all their SDKs into `Amplify` to streamline the integration process.

For instance in our iOS app the `Cognito` SDK had a number of issues that were resolved by moving to `Amplify`.

As you can see in the link below, this package is now maintained in the `Amplify` umbrella.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js

It used to be standalone here:

https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js

I would recommend going forward with `Amplify` as that is the direction that AWS development is headed internally, and `amazon-cognito-identity-js` is maintained as part of `Amplify` anyway.

Answer (score 31):

To add to the great answer by @DaveS. There are 3 official tools you can use to integrate Cognito in your app:

#### [Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js)

- Use it in client-side applications, where you'd use Amplify anyway - to leverage the premade auth UI components or to integrate with other services from the Amplify ecosystem: APIs, Analytics, Storage, etc.
- Does not support secret-enabled Cognito app clients.
- Cannot make authenticated (requiring AWS credentials) Cognito API calls (e.g. `adminCreateUser`) directly, but there's a [workaround](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin).

#### [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/main/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js)

- It is a much smaller package and it comes as a part of Amplify (hosted in the Amplify monorepo).
- It can still be used separately if you don't need any of the extra features provided by Amplify (save on the bundle size).
- Does not support secret-enabled Cognito app clients.
- Cannot make authenticated (requiring AWS credentials) Cognito API calls, e.g. `adminCreateUser`.
- Can be used in the backend (unauthenticated Cognito APIs only).

#### [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/index.html)

- Low-level as it can get.
- Provides access to all (authenticated and non-authenticated) Cognito APIs. For authenticated, make sure the code has access to AWS credentials.
- Can work with secret-enabled Cognito client apps (you need to sign the requests with the secret).
- Can be used in both client (for unauthenticated APIs only, otherwise you're exposing secrets) and server applications.

Code samples for all 3 can be found here: [AWS Cognito: Amplify vs amazon-cognito-identity-js vs AWS SDK](https://www.maxivanov.io/aws-cognito-amplify-vs-amazon-cognito-identity-js-vs-aws-sdk/).

Comment: hey Max, thanks for the great overview of these 3 official options and the article with code samples too!  It's really helped clarify the options for integrating Cognito into a web app client or server.